# ARC: Memory does not get reclaimed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I am working on an iPad (only) app and I stumbled across a weird problem. The app gets terminated after a memory warning on iPad 1 but works fine on iPad 2.
I am using ARC and targeting iOS 5. I use nibs and most of my assets are displayed using UIImageViews. I also have a few hundred buttons and plenty of gesture recognizers... I re-watched the WWDC11 videos (sessions 323 and 322) on ARC and I don't seem to be doing anything special.

The app is UIImage intensive, I am doing lots of animations using UIImage. I am however using the initWithContentsOfFile constructor rather than the imageNamed call. I'm trying to prevent the images from being cached by the system.

I'm also using GCD to schedule sound effects and to animate views. I'm always doing this on the main thread.

The app uses a UINavigationController that never has more than 1 UIViewController on it's stack. I can confirm that this is true because the didReceiveMemoryWarning only gets called on the current view controller (I'm logging the call).

The thing I don't understand is why Instruments is reporting high numbers (as if the view controllers don't get deallocated) in both the Allocations and VM Tracker instruments. The Allocations instrument shows a small drop when I navigate from one view controller to another (which is what I expect) but the VM Tracker Instrument shows that the Dirty Size is not dropping when I do the same thing. Eventually the app uses too much memory and gets terminated (on iPad 1). When I get memory warnings on the iPad 2 the app does NOT get terminated though...

It feels as if my images, sounds or views don't get destroyed and the memory does not get reclaimed... My object hierarchy is very basic and there should not be any retain cycles of any sort. I don't even have simple delegates...

Do you have any suggestions? I really don't want to release this app only for the iPad 2 or newer... It's an app for kids and it would be a pitty... I'd be so much happier to learn that I'm doing something wrong, as I really want to make sure this app is the best it can be...

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: Just a quick comment: I have spent a lot of time searching for leaks using instruments but it doesn't look like there are any. Plus, if there were, I'd think the iPad 2 would crash and burn eventually but it doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like answering my own question but I figured it could be helpful to future googlers. I implemented my own UIImage based animation and I no longer use the animationImages property. Turns out my memory issues are now gone as I no longer need to store all the images in memory and I load them as they are required using a timer.

I actually think that rolling out a custom animation is beneficial since it allows for callbacks and more powerful customisation options.

Once I'm happy with it and I feel like it's ready to be shared I will post the class(es) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to say, 'optimise' your objects by setting their properties to `nil` when certain things aren't needed -- so while you can't write a `dealloc` method anymore, you can do `self.object = nil` (when pertinent) which ends up doing something like this in a non-ARC world for an 'retain' (i.e., `strong`) property:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)newObject
{
   [object release]; // send release message to current object
   object = newObject; // set reference to newObject
   [object retain]; // send retain message to newObject
}
```

Now while in ARC you don't/can't write retain/release yourself in your code, the compiler inserts these calls for you, meaning that in practise, setting a property to `nil` would do this in the above example:

```
[object release]; // send release message to current object
object = nil; // set reference to nil
[object retain]; // send retain message to nil (no effect)
```

Moreover, this is just the tip of the iceberg -- you should make sure that there are [no retain cycles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) in your code, which could be resulting in objects leaking without recourse to their destruction. This means, that there may be places where you're using `strong` references to a property (i.e., an object), when you should be using a `weak` property. The difference being, that strong references are `retain`ed, and `weak` references are `assign`ed, the former having its retainCount incremented and the latter resulting in a property assignment that looks like this if handwritten:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)newObject
{
   object = newObject;
}
```

Comment: You can write `dealloc` methods - you just cant call `release` on anything, nor can you invoke `[super dealloc]`. But a `dealloc` method for cleanup is still kosher.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I am setting everything to nil in both viewDidDisappear and viewDidUnload. The dealloc does get called but has no impact on the actual memory footprint. Given the flat structure of the project there should be no retain cycles, but I'll check again one more time...

Comment: @Steve I have actually written my own dealloc just to see when it gets called. And it does get called when expected...

Comment: @Steve it is not KVC to use dealloc as a place to say self.object = nil though.

Comment: @AlanZeino - I don't think it ever was - was it? I stuck to `self.retainedSubviewProperty = nil` in `viewDidUnload` but always `[retainedSubviewProperty release]` in `dealloc`.